# How to Intersects two Union queries

Tags: sql, union

Hello I have Two Queries

One  is

```
SELECT userid_one AS id FROM `friends` WHERE `userid_two` = '$UserId' AND `requeststatus` ='accepted'
                    UNION 
SELECT userid_two AS id FROM `friends` WHERE  `userid_one` =  '$UserId' AND `requeststatus` ='accepted'
```

Its gives Me userids  41,38,61,62,64

Second Is

```
SELECT DISTINCT  `userid` FROM  `groupmembers` WHERE  `groupid` =24
```

It gives me 61,49,62

I want result userid they are not in Both Results
I.e:49,41,38,64,38

How can i do that

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take `UNION ALL` between first result (the one with join ) and second result.
So that the duplicate values persists. Now use `GROUP BY` to find non repeating `ids`.

```
SELECT id from 
       ( SELECT userid_one AS id FROM `friends` 
         WHERE `userid_two` = '$UserId' AND `requeststatus` ='accepted'

         UNION 

        SELECT userid_two AS id FROM `friends` 
        WHERE  `userid_one` =  '$UserId' AND `requeststatus` ='accepted'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DISTINCT  `userid`  AS id FROM  `groupmembers` WHERE  `groupid` =24
       ) A

        GROUP BY id having COUNT(1)=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query:

```
select id
from (your union)
group by id
having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your first results (the union) an alias of A, Give your second results an alias of B,

Then you can do :

```
SELECT id 
WHERE ((id IN A) AND NOT (id IN B)) OR (NOT (id IN A) AND (id IN B))
FROM (A UNION B)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT userid_one AS id FROM `friends` WHERE `userid_two` = '$UserId' AND `requeststatus` ='accepted'
                    UNION 
SELECT userid_two AS id FROM `friends` WHERE  `userid_one` =  '$UserId' AND `requeststatus` ='accepted'

) as t ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your database engine. However as JOIN are common among all, I hope following code will work for you

```
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT userid_one AS id FROM `friends` 
    WHERE `userid_two` = '$UserId' AND `requeststatus`='accepted'
  UNION 
    SELECT userid_two AS id FROM `friends` 
    WHERE  `userid_one` =  '$UserId' AND `requeststatus`='accepted'
) friends_union FULL OUTER JOIN 
  SELECT DISTINCT `userid` AS id FROM `groupmembers` WHERE `groupid` =24
) group_member ON friends_union.id = group_member.id
WHERE friends_union.id IS NULL OR group_member.id IS NULL
```

In case you are using MySQL then you have to search a workaround for **FULL OUTER JOIN**